# CheckBoxFor Nullable Boolean in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.Net MVC 4 in VB.Net,  I have seen a few other answers for how to make a checkbox for a nullable Boolean in c# .  Usually converting to VB.Net is pretty straight forward.  This I can not figure out.

Other answers say to do this..

> make a Boolean.cshtml in my EditorTemplates folder and sticking

```
@model bool?    
@Html.CheckBox("", Model.GetValueOrDefault())
```

So, I tried the VB equivelent, in EditorTemplates folder I made Boolean.vbhtml and put this

```
@model System.Nullable(of Boolean)
@Html.CheckBox("", Model.GetValueOrDefault)
```

then in my view I have

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.myNullableBool)
```

That code throws this exception:

> Object variable or With block variable not set.

there are a few different places I found with pretty similar c# examples very similar to what is posted here.  Does anyone know how to get this to work in VB.Net?

**EDIT**

This is kind of what I'm trying to do (if it worked it'd be even better)

```
@model System.Nullable(of Boolean)
@Html.CheckBox("", If(Model is Nothing, False, Model))
```

Comment: What's the purpose of having Nullable(of Boolean) in your ViewModel but setting it with a checkbox? Still there are three possible 'values'. Better use two different ViewModels instead. And if you currently binding against you DomainModel i would recommend using ViewModels instead.

Comment: @milter - i always want one of 2 values true or false , the db has to stay nullable because data can come from other sources , and from those sources they can be null , in my case if it happens to be null - forcing it to false is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`HTML checkbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#checkbox) has 2 states:

- checked
- unchecked

Translating into .NET [`boolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) type terms this means:

- True
- False

So attempting to bind a Nullable boolean property on your view model to a checkbox hardly makes any logical sense. A nullable boolean has 3 states in .NET:

- Nothing (null in C#)
- True
- False

So as you can see the HTML semantic of a checkbox simply doesn't fit your view model type. It's not surprising by the way why the Html.CheckBoxFor helper expects a boolean property, not nullable boolean.

So I would recommend you modifying the type of your view model property to be a non-nullable boolean if you want to bind it to a checkbox.

Otherwise you could always have a `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Boolean.vbhtml` custom editor template with the following content:

```
@ModelType Nullable(Of Boolean)
@Html.CheckBox("", If(Model.HasValue, Model.Value, False))
```

But those kind of hacks should not be necessary if you design your view models correctly i.e. to match the requirements of your views.

Comment: I probably will change view model , but I tried your code and got "Public member 'HasValue' on type 'Boolean' not found."

Comment: The `ModelType` of your custom editor template should be `@ModelType Nullable(Of Boolean)` (as shown in my answer), not `@ModelType Boolean`.

Comment: ahhh , i had "@model"  , I needed "@ModelType"  , thanks for the help  ,  I probably will change the ViewModel. but still I feel better now , i've been reading about custom editor templates and now got one to work